# Expressing a complex number expression in $a+ib$ form

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

How would I go about expressing a term like this in the form $a + ib$?

$$ \frac{(\cos \alpha+ i \ \sin \alpha)(cos \beta+ i \ \sin \beta)}{(\cos \gamma+ i \ \sin \gamma)(\cos\delta+ i \ \sin \delta)} $$

I tried rationalizing the denominator and got an expression as just a product of 4 terms but then I am unable to proceed as I am not aware of any formula for the cosine of the sum of more than 2 angles.

The expression I got after rationalizing is:
$$ (\cos \alpha+ i \ \sin \alpha)(\cos \beta + i \ \sin \beta)(\cos \gamma- i \ \sin \gamma)(\cos\delta- i \ \sin\delta) $$

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Three of the parenthesis can be simplified quickly using polar form

Comment: Hint: Write the numbers in polar form

Comment: Euler's formula $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$ may be helpful

Comment: Don't try to be elegant.  Multiply everything out in the numerator and denominator to achieve the form $\frac{s + it}{u + iv}.$  Then multiply both the numerator and denominator by $(u - iv)$.  The denominator will become a real number.

Comment: Re previous comment, there is something of a shortcut.  An elementary result from complex analysis is that $e^{i\theta_1} \times e^{i\theta_2} = e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}$.  What this means is that 
$$[\cos(\theta_1) + i\sin(\theta_1)] \times [\cos(\theta_2) + i\sin(\theta_2)] = [\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + i\sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2)].$$

Comment: I suggest there is a typo in the question and the "silly" term should be rather $\cos\delta + i\sin\delta$.

Comment: Is it $\cos \beta$ or $\cos \delta$ in the denominator?

Comment: @ancientmathematician yeah, I corrected that

Comment: In that case @Rounak has pretty well told you how to do it.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yeah i have figured it out, it was pretty trivial though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments. We can use the euler's formula to give us:

$\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha)=e^{i\alpha}$

$\cos(\beta)+i\sin(\beta)=e^{i\beta}$

$\cos(\gamma)+i\sin(\gamma)=e^{i\gamma}$

$\cos(\delta)+i\sin(\delta)=e^{i\delta}$

Which would give us-

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{(\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha))(\cos(\beta)+i\sin(\beta))}{(\cos(\gamma)+i\sin(\gamma))(\cos(\delta)+i\sin(\delta)}}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\frac{e^{i\alpha}e^{i\beta}}{e^{i\gamma}e^{i\delta}}}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=e^{i(\alpha+\beta-\gamma-\delta)}}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\cos(\beta+\alpha-\gamma-\delta)+i\sin(\beta+\alpha-\gamma-\delta)}$

Comment: Now that he has corrected the question you can deal easily with it.

Comment: @ancientmathematician. Corrected it.